R scratch to compute coreness of each vertex (k-core of graph)
I tried to implement the k-core algorithm in R. However, the result is different from the one in igraph::coreness.
The function I created from my understanding of this algorithm in R is this:
my_kcores <- function(W){
  deg    <- colSums(W)
  maxd   <- max(deg)
  kcores <- integer( length(deg) )
  W_copy <- W
  for ( d in 0:maxd ){
    while ( any( (deg > 0) & (deg <= d) ) ){
      W_copy[ deg <= d ,] <- W_copy[, deg <= d ] <- 0
      deg                 <- colSums(W_copy)
    }
    kcores[ deg > d ] <- d + 1
  }
  return(kcores)
}

For example:
library(igraph)
W <- matrix(c(0,0,0,1,
              0,1,0,0,
              0,0,1,1,
              1,0,1,0),
            nrow = 4,
            byrow = TRUE)
g <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(W, mode = "undirected", weighted = FALSE)
coreness(g)
# [1] 1 2 2 1

my_kcores(W)
# [1] 1 1 1 1

all.equal(coreness(g), my_kcores(W))
# [1] "Mean relative difference: 0.5"


I don't think your algorithm is problematic, but you should be aware that your diagonal entry 1s in W, which indicate self loops, say, you have in-/out-wards arcs pointed to itself at the same time. In that case, colSums(W) gives the incorrect degree information and thus results in undesired output, i.e., different from coreness(g).


Tweak It
You should have a preprocess of W, then run my_kcores, e.g.,
> (WW <- `diag<-`(W, 2 * diag(W)))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0    1
[2,]    0    2    0    0
[3,]    0    0    2    1
[4,]    1    0    1    0

> my_kcores(WW)
[1] 1 2 2 1

or you can finish the preprocessing within my_kcores, e.g.,
my_kcores <- function(W) {
  diag(W) <- diag(W) * 2 # count both in-/out-wards degrees together
  deg <- colSums(W)
  maxd <- max(deg)
  kcores <- integer(length(deg))
  W_copy <- W
  for (d in 0:maxd) {
    while (any((deg > 0) & (deg <= d))) {
      W_copy[deg <= d, ] <- W_copy[, deg <= d] <- 0
      deg <- colSums(W_copy)
    }
    kcores[deg > d] <- d + 1
  }
  return(kcores)
}


Yes, but by this way the result of igraph::coreness will change as well, right?

@pada4mdapa you should make sure that the igraph object g has the same degree information as W represents

I accidentally found this webpage that does more or less the same with me in MATLAB and I feel that I must post it:
https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/dgleich/packages/matlab_bgl/core_numbers_example/core_numbers_example.html
So the algorithm is correct (phew!!!). But, there is probably a difference at the implementation between the igraph::coreness and the my_kcores.

yes, this is a good reference. you should check how the matrix A looks like. As I said that in my answer, the problem is not your algorithm implementation, but the format of input adjacency matrix.

Therefore, adding something like diag(W) <- diag(W) * 2 in the beginning of the function should solve this problem? I mean modifying the beginning of the function and not its input. It seems to give identical results with igraph::coreness.

Yes, you can do it within the function
